# How to find out InfiniBand installation path

Tags: mpi, infiniband, mvapich2

I want to compile MVAPICH2 myself, but not sure where to find `psm.h` file, it cant be found in default places.

Anyone knows that which command I can use to find InfiniBand?

Comment: Infiniband is a hardware component as well as a software one.  Switches typically cost thousands and thousands of dollars.  Before we start troubleshooting the software, please verify that the hardware is installed and configured.  Then read the manual.

Comment: You need to have OFED (OpenFabrics Enterprise Distribution) development packages installed and optionally DAPL (not sure if MVAPICH2 supports DAPL). From OFED you'd most likely need the verbs API `libibverbs`. Most distributions provide prepackaged OFED binaries but they usually lag alot behind the current version.

Comment: Of cause it is installed and well configured.

Answer (score 1):

psm.h is for QLogic InfiniPath.  On RHEL derivatives it should be in the infinipath-psm-devel package.  You probably aren't using QLogic though.

Try specifying the MVAPICH2 channel explicitly.  For the traditional mrail channel, run configure as

```
./configure --with-device=ch3:mrail --with-rdma=gen2
```

Or, for the Nemesis channel with IB netmod

```
./configure --with-device=ch3:nemesis:ib
```

Of course, you need to have the devel OFED packages installed.